# Matplotlib is not showing my scatterplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, iris-dataset

When I use plt.show the plot only shows the PCA lines and not a scatterplot of the first 2 iris features

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn import decomposition

x = np.load("iris_features.npy")[:, :2]
y = np.load("iris_labels.npy")
idx = np.where(y != 0)
x = x[idx]
x[:, 0] -= x[:, 0].mean()
x[:, 1] -= x[:, 1].mean()


pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(x)
v = pca.explained_variance_ratio_


plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], marker='o', color='b')
ax = plt.axes()
x0 = v[0] * pca.components_[0, 0]
y0 = v[0] * pca.components_[0, 1]
ax.arrow(0, 0, x0, y0, head_width=0.05,) head_length=0.1, fc='r', ec='r')
x1 = v[1] * pca.components_[1, 0]
y1 = v[1] * pca.components_[1, 1]
ax.arrow(0, 0, x1, y1, head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1, fc='r', ec='r')
plt.xlabel("$x_0$", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("$x_1$", fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfRbq.png)

[What the correct plot should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15rjg.png)

Comment: Your example code has a syntax error: `SyntaxError: unmatched ')'` on line 22

Comment: True, for my testing i removed that parenthesis and it woks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine using the iris dataset from sklearn, and produces the expected result. You can try that, or you can share your dataset in a testable way, as in principle you could have whatever data in these csv files.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()

x = iris.data
y = iris.target

idx = np.where(y != 0)
x = x[idx]
....  # your code continues here
```

If that doesn't work, share or directly update your python, matplotlib version.